# Given $f(x) = e^{-x} \sin x, $ Find $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ if it exists. Justify using limits definition.

Tags: real-analysis

> Given $$f(x) = e^{-x} \sin x, $$
> Find $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ if it exists. Justify using directly the following definition:
>
> $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=L$ if $f$ is defined on an interval $(a, \infty)$ and for each $\epsilon >0$ there is a number $\beta$ such that:
> $$| f(x) - L| < \epsilon \quad\text{if}\quad x> \beta.$$

Taking the limit:

$$ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} e^{-x} \sin x = 0$$

By definition for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have:
$$ |e^{-x} \sin x - 0|< \epsilon$$
$$ |e^{-x} \sin x |< \epsilon$$

Let's find some $M>0$ in terms of $x$ such that:
$$|e^{-x} \sin x | \leq M < \epsilon$$

As $|\sin x |$ fluctuates from $0$ to $1$, $$|e^{-x} \sin x | \leq |e^{-x}|$$

Since $e^{-x}>0 ,\forall x$, we have
$$|e^{-x} \sin x | \leq e^{-x}$$

Let's solve for $x$
$$e^{-x} < \epsilon$$
$$\ln (e^{-x}) < \ln (\epsilon)$$
$$-x< \ln \epsilon$$
$$x> -\ln \epsilon$$

It follows that for any arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, the limit $|f(x) - 0|< \epsilon$ is true when $x>-\ln \epsilon$

Is this a correct reasoning? can it be improved?

Any input is much appreciated

Comment: Correct reasoning. No actual need to speak of that constant $M$, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Then
$$
\left|\frac{\sin x}{e^x}-0\right| \le \frac{1}{e^x} \le \varepsilon
$$
whenever $x \ge -\log \varepsilon$. (In particular, yes the reasoning is correct.)

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what OP did... I don't see how this is an answer to OP's question (Is this a correct reasoning?)

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning is correct, I just suggest you change the part of the proof where you say

> By definition for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have:
>   $$ |e^{-x} \sin x - 0|< \epsilon$$
>   $$ |e^{-x} \sin x |< \epsilon$$

This part is confusing, because you don't **have** that yet, it's actually what you want to prove. So, instead, I would say

> By definition, we must prove for every $\epsilon >0$ that $$ |e^{-x} \sin x - 0|< \epsilon$$

Also, you could write just a word or two about how you know that the final four inequalities are equivalent. FOr example, you know that $e^{-x}<\epsilon\iff \ln(e^{-x})<\ln(\epsilon)$ because both numbers are positive and $\ln$ is a strictly increasing function.

And finally, just remove the whole line where you talk about the constant $M$. You bring it up, then never mention it again - the proof works just fine without it.

---

Other than that, your proof is OK.